# What does 过得 mean in 过得比较舒服?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

In the following sentence [on this article](https://www.huarenjie.com/thread-5510973-1-1.html):

> 加拿大是一个很美的国家，领土面积特别大，但是人口才4000万，**过得**比较舒服，所以现在也有越来越多的人选择留学这裡。

What does 过得 mean here? And how does it work grammatically in this context?

Comment: It would be easier to understand if the writer did not omit the topic "生活" and wrote "生活过得比较舒服"

Comment: BTW is 这裡 here a typo? Or different from 这里?

Comment: 裡 is the traditional character of  simplified 里

Comment: @TangHo I see. Not sure then why the author suddenly used the traditional character...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"过得舒服" is "生活 过得舒服" omitted the topic "生活"(life) or  "过生活"(living life)

得 in 过得舒服 is a 'degree/result verb particle' that indicate the degree or result of the verb 过

> "过生活 过(得) 舒服" = live life (to the point of) being comfortable
>
> "过生活" can be omitted if it is clearly implied in the context
>
> or you can just remove the first 过 and use 生活 as the topic directly and write "生活 过(得) 舒服"

More example:

> "看电影 看(得) 高興" = watch movies (to the degree of) being happy
>
> "看电影" can be omitted if it is clearly implied in the context

Comment: Thanks. How can I know 过 is a shortened form of 过生活? Chinese language has so many of such shortened forms but it is practically impossible to come up with what is a shortened form of what...

Comment: And 过 means "spend" in this context and works as a verb - am I correct?

Comment: See my edition. "过得舒服" is "生活 过得舒服" omitted the object "生活" or "过生活 过得舒服" omitted the topic "过生活"

Comment: Yeah I understand. But I can't decide how 生活 comes suddenly. It likely relies on the context, but it is very difficult to complement it for non-natives.

Comment: 1.Yes, 过 is a verb that can mean "spend" , 2. If I just say "看得高興" you would not know what object or topic I am referring to. The topic "看电影" must be indicated somewhere in the context

Comment: Edited again,  the topic is either "生活"(life) or "过生活"(living life), and the comment is "过得舒服", it is a common [topic + comment/ opinion] sentence structure.